# scrollbar for the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, struts-1

I want to show scroll bar for the drop down list so that the user can select any **one item** from the available list. The drop down menu should show 5 items and a scroll bar to drag and see remaining items in the list when the user clicks on the drop down list. To show the drop down list i am using struts html tag library. Below is the struts html code to show drop down list.

```
 <html:select name="myForm" property="city" styleId="city" tabindex="1" title="Please Select City">
  <html:options property="city" labelProperty="city"/>
 </html:select>
```

Do i need to write javascript function to achieve scroll bar for the `<html:options>`. I cannot use jQuery as my application does not support jQuery libraries. Please suggest how can i achieve this using javascript function.

Comment: this coding is  html6?

Comment: what has this got to do with Java?

Comment: I am using struts tag library from java.@ScaryWombat

Comment: @NelsonTan - no..i am using struts tag library from java.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign a class to option list and add overflow equal to auto. I simply added with style.

```
<html:select name="myForm" property="city" styleId="city" tabindex="1" title="Please Select City">
```

Comment: Can you please add the <html:options> with your answer above so that any one searching with this can find a solution here and i can accept your answer.Thankyou

Comment: I want to show first 5 items in the list with scroll bar, overflow equal to auto may not satisfy my requirement. @Mohsin Ali

Comment: there is no class attribute for <html:options>